# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on class from .aar file in Android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, aar

I've added an arr file to my project as a module, and added that module as a dependency to my app's module. I can import the class that throws the error like so:

```
import com.example.my_project.MyProject;
```

and it compiles without error. But when I compile and run it (without any reeference to the code! All I have is the dependency!!!!!), then I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.slyce.slyce_messaging.SlyceMessagingApi
............
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.my_project.MyProject" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/xyz.matthewpage.testtest-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/xyz.matthewpage.testtest-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Anyone run into this issue before? I tried a lot of the other threads from stack overflow, but all of those used maven while Android Studio uses gradle. Any ideas for a Gradle fix?

Comment: First of all show you gradle configs (including build.gradle ...), second I don't understand your project structure you add a new module and that module has a single aar dependency and nothing else, so why don't you add your war dependency to your main module!